# Google Contacts API - Java: Cannot update contacts

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to update contacts of my Google Apps users through the Google Contacts API and a Java app.

I am able to get the contacts of this particular user, but if I want to update a certain contact, the update fails.

My code:

```
package com.haha;

import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.Query.CustomParameter;
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.GoogleOAuthParameters;
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthHmacSha1Signer;
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthSigner;
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthParameters.OAuthType;
import com.google.gdata.client.contacts.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.ContactEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.ContactFeed;

public class ContactsMain {

    private static final String APP_NAME = "haha.com";
    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "haha.com";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "123456";
    private static final String SCOPE_CONTACTS = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";
    private static final String FEED_URL_CONTACTS = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base";
    private static final String MY_USER = "user@haha.com";
    private static final String MAX_RESULTS = "10000";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // Create the service
            ContactsService myService = new ContactsService(APP_NAME);

            // OAuth
            GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
            oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
            oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
            oauthParameters.setScope(SCOPE_CONTACTS);
            oauthParameters.setOAuthType(OAuthType.TWO_LEGGED_OAUTH);
            OAuthSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();

            // Authenticate the service
            myService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, signer);

            // Build the query
            Query myQuery = new Query(new URL(FEED_URL_CONTACTS));
            myQuery.addCustomParameter(new CustomParameter("xoauth_requestor_id", MY_USER));
            myQuery.addCustomParameter(new CustomParameter("max-results", MAX_RESULTS));

            // Get all contacts
            ContactFeed resultFeed = myService.query(myQuery, ContactFeed.class);

            for (ContactEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {

                if (entry.hasName() && entry.getName().hasFamilyName()) {

                    if ((entry.getName().getFamilyName().getValue()).equals("Lastname")) {

                        System.out.println("Contact 'Lastname' was found");

                        entry.getName().getFamilyName().setValue("Lastname-EDIT");
                        entry.update();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The console output of Eclipse:

```
Contact 'Lastname' was found
java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
    at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96)
    at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.<init>(AuthenticationException.java:67)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.update(Service.java:1563)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.update(Service.java:1530)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.update(GoogleService.java:597)
    at com.google.gdata.data.BaseEntry.update(BaseEntry.java:639)
    at com.haha.ContactsMain.main(ContactsMain.java:60)
```

The first line on the console output prooves that the contacts can be read. The ContactsMain.java:60 means the following line:

```
entry.update();
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here? Do I have to add some tokens to the "entry" object before I want it to update?

Every help is very appreciated. Thank you very much,

Marco

Comment: If I put "myService.setUserCredentials(MY_USER, MY_PASSWORD);" after the line "myService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, signer);" then it works. But I thought, that the idea behind two-legged oauth is, that you don't need any user passwords? It is very confusing, because I can read the contacts without the user password, but for updating I need the password. In my opinion: really strange...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that only read-access is enabled for 2-legged OAuth, but not write access (this is what happens also with the provisioning api - we've been trying to get write access from Googe for the longest time, but they never committed to doing it). If I am correct, then that is very likely why the update is failing for you. (the exception points to a lack of proper authentication).

Comment: BTW, my answer is just a guess. Please double check with Google's documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've just read the documentation but as far as I read, 2-legged OAuth should have write access.